# POST login data to android webview

Tags: android, webview, postdata

i am trying to doing something like this for my university, User key in their username and password into the textbox, after the user click the login button, my application will post login data to the webserver URL. After successful login, my application webview will display user's details.

POST login data >> to webserver >> HTML response >> WebView

This is my full code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button ok,back,exit;
    TextView result;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

    }

    public void postLoginData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://icems.mmu.edu.my/sfik/sik_vlogin.jsp");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
            String username = uname.getText().toString();

            EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
            String password = pword.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("studid", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwd", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("MMU", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            WebView AchievementWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewAchievement);
            WebSettings webSettings = AchievementWeb.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

           AchievementWeb.loadUrl("https://icems.mmu.edu.my/sfik/sik_studinfo.jsp");

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.w("MMU", str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                Log.w("MMU", "Login success");

            }else
            {
                Log.w("MMU", "Login fail");

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } 

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == ok){
            postLoginData();

        }
    }

}
```

This is my logcat. The application runs well, based on the logcat{01-03 01:43:03.587: W/MMU(809)}, i think i have successful posting the login data, but when running my webview, its still asking me to login my username and password. so my problem is, how could i pass my post data to webview? I need some help here... thank you.

```
01-03 01:42:50.416: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 230K, 13% free 2694K/3088K, paused 76ms, total 78ms
01-03 01:42:50.436: I/dalvikvm-heap(809): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.392MB for 635812-byte allocation
01-03 01:42:50.516: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 11% free 3314K/3712K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
01-03 01:42:50.546: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 3313K/3712K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
01-03 01:42:50.566: I/dalvikvm-heap(809): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.868MB for 500416-byte allocation
01-03 01:42:50.626: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 3802K/4204K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
01-03 01:42:51.268: D/(809): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a2055d8, tid 809
01-03 01:42:52.576: E/cutils-trace(809): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-03 01:42:53.446: D/TilesManager(809): Starting TG #0, 0x2a269070
01-03 01:42:57.906: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(809): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
01-03 01:42:57.906: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(809):   in android.widget.EditText{4171f580 VFED..CL .F....I. 135,151-285,215 #7f050004 app:id/txt_password}
01-03 01:42:57.906: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(809):   0: sent at 125371000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=125371, downTime=125269, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
01-03 01:43:01.906: W/MMU(809): Execute HTTP Post Request
01-03 01:43:03.096: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 957K, 25% free 3358K/4476K, paused 43ms, total 48ms
01-03 01:43:03.587: W/MMU(809):  <html><head><title>Student Information</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <font size="1"> <body link="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFF00"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  <tr valign="top">     <td width="32%"><img src="images/sfik.jpg">&nbsp;</td>    <td width="34%" valign="middle" nowrap>       <div align="center"><font size="4" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;      </font></div>    </td>    <td align="right" width="34%"><img src="staff/images/mmulogo_small.jpg" width="300" height="74">&nbsp;</td>  </tr></table><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#336699">  <tr>     <td><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FFFFFF"><b>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="sik_studinfo.jsp">Student       Info</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="sik_invoices.jsp">Invoices</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;       <a href="sik_payment.jsp">Payment</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="sik_refund.jsp">Refund</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;       <a href="sik_allowance.jsp">Allowance</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="sik_ledger.jsp">Student       Statement </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="sik_supp.jsp">Supplementary Paper </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="sik_convo.jsp">Convo Fees </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="sik_summon.jsp">Summon</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<!--a href="sik_onlinepayment.jsp"--><a href="http://www.maybank2u.com.my/" target="_blank">Maybank2u Online       Payment</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.cimbclicks.com.my/" target="_blank">CIMBClicks Online       Payment</a></b></font></td>    <td align="right"> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FFFFFF"><b>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="logout.jsp">Logout       </a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="logout.jsp"> </a></b></font> </td>  </tr></table><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#3366CC"><tr><td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" > <tr valign="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><td> <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>   <td width="62%">    <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">    <b>Student ID : xxxxxxxxxx</b>    </font>  </td>                <td width="38%" align="right"> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><b>Name                   : xxxxxx xxxxxx</b> </font> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">&nbsp;                   </font> </td>    </tr></table></td>    </tr></table></td>  </tr></table></font></font> <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#3366CC">  <tr>     <td>       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#3366CC">        <tr>           <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">             <table width="78%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#3366CC" align="center">              <tr>                 <td bgcolor="#3366CC">                   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">                       <td align="center"><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong><font size="1">IMPORTANT                         ! </font></strong></font> <p align="left"><font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br>                          Dear Students, </font></p>                        <p align="left"><font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">For                           those who paid at CIMB branches (EXCEPT on campus branch),                           please submit the copy of bank slip/remittance document/other                           proof of payment to Finance Counter or fax it over to                           06-2315605 (Melaka) or 03-83125030 (Cyberjaya) and don't                           forget to write your ID on it!</font></p>                        <p align="left">                        </p> <p align=
01-03 01:43:03.606: W/MMU(809): Login fail
```

Comment: I think your you had succesfully login, but there is problem in your if-else statement. You are checking whether the result(i.e String str== true), but it returns html format response, therefore else statement executes and print "Login fail"

Comment: hmm, any idea how to change my if else statement?